# Matlab - Solving a diferential equation

Tags: matlab, ode

i'm trying to solve this equation:

y''+3yy''       with          y(0)=0     ;       y(2)=1

I've tried using bvp4c and i know i have to turn it into a system of DE but i am really stuck, any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

I've tried this, but really is just guessing

```
function sss=sos()
solinit=bvpinit(linspace(0,2,10),[1,0,0]);
answ=bvp4c(@twoode,@bcfun,solinit)
x=linspace(0,2);
y=deval(answ,x);
plot(x,y(1,:));
end

function dydx=twoode(x,y)
dydx=[y(3),3*y(1)+y(2)];
end

function res=bcfun(ya,yb)
res=[ya(1),yb(1)+2];
end
```

Comment: What's the RHS?  Do you mean (1+3y)y'' = 0?  Here's the solution according to Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B3y)y%27%27%20%3D%200

Comment: @duffymo I think there is a type - it should be y'' + 3 * y * y' = 0

Answer (score 0):

Start with (if the original equation is y'' + 3 * y * y' = 0)

```
function sss = sos()
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0, 2, 10), [1, 0]);
answ = bvp4c(@twoode, @bcfun, solinit);
x = linspace(0, 2);
y = deval(answ, x);
plot(x, y(1, :));
end

function dydx = twoode(x, y)
dydx = [y(2); -3 * y(1) * y(2)];
end

function res = bcfun(ya, yb)
res = [ya(1); yb(1) - 1];
end
```

[image: Graph]